MathOperator gives weird spacing in compositions, products
I have defined a math operator as follows:
\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}

When writing a composition like \Id \circ g I get weird spacing around the g. Same with products, say \Id \times g. Why does this happen?
As a workaround I can write {\Id} \circ g and get good spacing. I don't know why this fixes it, but it does. Is this workaround necessary, or is there some better way?
Here is a minimal example illustrating the issue:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  f = \Id \circ g
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  f = {\Id} \circ g
\end{equation*}

\end{document}



I realize now that it is probably that the $\circ$ symbol gets treated like an argument of the operator. The remaining parts of the question are still relevant, though. Is adding brackets the correct way to deal with it?

Your “Id” isn't an operator. Just do \mathrm{Id}.

Please always provide a small test document that shows the problem. You have only provided fragments of code and images that were clearly generated by different code. (the code uses an operator Int and the images are generated from an unshown code using Id

@DavidCarlisle Sorry, that's just a typo.

The spacing you show does the right thing for \log -2  where the mathbin - loses its mathbin status and becomes a mathord close to the 2, just as the circle operator you show loses its mathbin status if between a \mathop and a \mathord

@ummg if you provided a test document and posted images generated by the code shown, then that would not happen.

@DavidCarlisle I will add a test document. Give me a moment.

The spacing you show does the right thing for \log -2  where the mathbin - loses its mathbin status and becomes a mathord close to the 2, just as the circle operator you show loses its mathbin status if between a \mathop and a \mathord
You could define
\newcommand\fcompose[2]{{#1}\circ{#2}}
and then use
\fcompose\Id g

If you are doing a lot of this and want to ensure that \circ is always used as a \mathbin between two \mathord atoms, as the brace group always forces a math atom to lose its math class and be treated as  \mathord


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand\fcompose{m}{
  \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl{}
  \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{\l_tmpa_tl\tl_set_eq:NN\l_tmpa_tl\circ{##1}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

$\fcompose{f,g,h,\Id}$



\end{document}


That's a good suggestion! The only issue I see with it is when it comes to multiple compositions of more than 2 functions. Then it seems i would have to write something like \fcompose{f}{\fcompose g h} to mean f \circ g \circ h. The latter is more natural, of course.

@ummg it would be easy enough to have \fcompose{f,g,h,\Id} with a comma list if that's what you want.

I see. How would one define that, so that it works for any number of terms?

@ummg I added an example

\DeclareMathOperator is not a shorthand for “define a command that produces some text in upright type”.
See What's the difference between \mathrm and \operatorname? for more information.
Your “Id” looks like an ordinary symbol, that stands for the identity map, I guess. You should define it like
\newcommand{\Id}{\mathrm{Id}}

Full example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Id}{\mathrm{Id}}

\begin{document}

$f=\Id\circ f=f\circ\Id$

$\Id(x)=x$

\end{document}


You might want to do differently. Here's a possibility. I also provide the *-variant in order to redefine existing functions.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareFunction}{smm}{%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\let#2\relax}%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#2}{t\circ}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}{{\operatorname{#3}}\circ}{\operatorname{#3}}%
  }%
}

\DeclareFunction{\Id}{Id}
\DeclareFunction*{\log}{log}
\DeclareFunction*{\exp}{exp}

\begin{document}

$f=\Id\circ f=f\circ\Id$ \qquad $\log\circ\exp=\Id$

$\Id(x)=x$ \qquad $\exp(x)=e^x$

$\Id x=x$ \qquad $\exp x=e^x$

\end{document}



Id is a function just like log though: Id(x) = x for all x so declaring it as \mathop isn't at all unreasonable I think. Or to put it another way the question could have been asked about \log  compose g, would you have redefined \log ?

I have to agree with David here. It is not uncommon that I might want to write $\Id x$ instead of $\Id(x)$. (Maybe specifically Id is not the best example here, but you get the idea.)

@ummg See edit.
